# Can i do a inner "With" inside another "With" in SQL?

Tags: sql, db2, double, left-join, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to use multiple SQL `With` clauses.

The reason of me using multiple `With` is that I'm sending this SQL to a AS400 project. The `With TEMP` has to be obligatory instead of `Temp2` that has to be optional.

I can't figure out how to do it. This SQL still throws an error:

```
With Temp2 As 
(
    With Temp As 
    (
        Select Name, Surname, Age 
        From People
        Where Age > 18
    )
    Select A.*, B.* 
    From Temp A 
    Left Join City B on B.Name = A.Name 
                     and B.Surname = A.Surname 
    Where B.City = "Venice"
)
Select * 
From Temp2 C 
Left Join State D on D.City = C.City
```

I'd like to understand how I can do something like that.

Comment: `WITH` has to be the first statement in a batch, so there can't be a `WITH` nested inside another `WITH`.

Comment: You can do `WITH Temp AS (.......), Temp2 AS ( ....[reference Temp]...) SELECT .......`.

Comment: Is this the accurate schema of the `City` table? Does `City` have `Name` and `Surname`? It would seem that this schema is incorrectly de-normalized and might need another look. If you are doing it this way, you may as well just put the `City` in the `People` table.  Regardless, can you provide an example of your data and what you are trying to extract from it? What you are listing can likely be done through a simple `JOIN`.

Comment: @Shawn `City` is a "dumb" table where people are saved with `Name` and `Surname`. Those records are related to their national city.
It's a simple database. Btw thank you for your answere

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, any CTE can reference a CTE that is created before it. The first CTE must be prefaced by "With" and terminated with a comma, which allows for another CTE to be created.

```
with temp as 
(
    select name, surname, age 
    from people
    where age > 18
),
temp2 as 
    (
        select a.*, b.* 
        from temp a 
        left join city b 
            on b.name = a.name 
            and b.surname = a.surname 
        where b.city = "Venice"
    )

select * 
from temp2 c 
left join state d 
    on d.city = c.city
;
```

This is functionally equivalent to the query below, which does not require any CTE's.

```
select *
from people as a
join city b 
    on b.name = a.name
    and b.surname = a.surname 
    and b.city = "Venice"
left join state c
    on c.city = b.city
where a.age > 18
;
```

Comment: An explanation would also be nice `:-)`

Comment: I was about to post the simpler `JOIN` syntax as an alternative answer. +1 for beating me to it!

Answer (score 0):

For what you are describing, you shouldn't need either CTEs or subqueries. Just use regular `JOIN`s.

```
SELECT p.Name, p.Surname, p.Age, C.City, s.StateName, s.CountryName 
FROM People p
INNER JOIN City c ON p.Name = c.Name
    AND p.Surname = c.Surname
    AND c.City = 'Venice'
LEFT OUTER JOIN State s ON c.City = s.City
WHERE p.Age > 18
```

See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=6d16c8325ee1da354588ddddc75bb162 for demo.